# PyQt5: how to add a row by pressing a push button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a table in my program using PyQt5, i want to add row by pressing a button manually, how can i do that?
I am new to pyqt, so i have no idea, I've searched and didn't find anything good.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

create a slot for the clicked signal of the button, then connect them like

```
button.clicked.connect(add_row_to_my_table)

def add_row_to_my_table():
    ...
    # see below on how to add a row to table
```

if you are using QTableView, do it via you model as in QTableView.model()

1. call beginInsertRows() before inserting new rows into the data structure
2. insert a row into the data structure
3. call endInsertRows() immediately afterwards

check whether you existing implementation supports "inserting a row"

1. check that rowCount() can reflect the change
2. check that data() can provide required data for the new  row
3. check that flags() can provide required flag for the new row

if your are using QTableWidget,

1. insert an empty row: void QTableWidget::insertRow(int row)
2. fill in data: void QTableWidget::setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem *item)